# Angular 4 - Components Not Loading After Custom Routing

Tags: angular

I've followed the Heros tutorial from Angular's website.  I have 2 components that I added with custom routing inside `app-routing.module.ts` However, once I set up routes, neither of my components Address or Auth load when I visit their route.  The app shell app.component loads along with its HTML just fine but my components do not.  I added `ngOnInit` to my components and they **do not** fire when I visit the url, **so for some reason my components are not working after I added custom routing.** When I visit either `/address` or `/auth` the app component fires and I see

> INSIDE APP COMPONENT

in the console, however I do not see any console log from the address or auth component.

app.module

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule }    from '@angular/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AddressComponent } from './address.component';
import { AuthComponent } from './auth.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AddressComponent,
    AuthComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }             from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { AddressComponent }      from './address.component';
import { AuthComponent }  from './auth.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/address', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'address', component: AddressComponent },
  { path: 'auth', component: AuthComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

auth.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-auth',
    templateUrl: './auth.component.html'
})
export class AuthComponent implements OnInit{
  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log("INSIDE APP COMPONENT");
  }
}
```

auth.component.html

```
<div>
    <h3>Authentication & Authorization Page </h3>
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log("INSIDE APP COMPONENT");
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you should change the:  { path: '', redirectTo: '/address', pathMatch: 'full' } ==>  { path: '', redirectTo: 'address', pathMatch: 'full' }.

Comment: What does your HTML look like? Do you have a router outlet defined?

Comment: It's pretty hard since there is no error log. Could you provide a github or a plunkr of the issue ? It would be really easier, even though it seems like a minor issue to fix.

Comment: @Thinhbk Removing the / didn't change anything.  The redirect still works but the component still do not load.

Comment: @DeborahK Thanks-You.  I didn't have `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in my `app.component.html` New to angular 4 so I didn't realize this.

Comment: Glad that resolved it. Consider working through the tour of heroes tutorial here: https://angular.io/ or take a course such as this one:https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/angular-2-getting-started-update (you can sign up for a free week). Spending a few hours learning some of the details and idiosyncrasies could save you loads of time as you build your app. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in `app.component.html` as that is where the components render.